# DateTime Subtract Minutes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm using DateTime.Subtract in my two DateTime.

```
dt1 = 2015-07-27 15:43:32
dt2 = 2015-07-27 16:45:34

int dif_minutes = dt1.Subtract(dt2).Minutes; // dif_minutes = 2
```

the dif_minutes value was only 2, but my expected value was 62.

is there any way i can achieve that?

Comment: One of the reasons suggested when mousing over the down-vote arrow is "this question does not show any research effort", which is why I down-voted.  VS has a Help menu for a reason but this question shows that it was obviously not used.  It would have taken a few minutes only to find out how the `Minutes` and `TotalMinutes` properties work.  If you haven't read the appropriate documentation then you haven't tried to solve the problem yourself, so posting a question here is premature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of .Minutes, you want to use the .TotalMinutes property

```
     var dif_minutes = dt1.Subtract(dt2).Minutes; // dif_minutes = 2
```

Ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that TotalMinutes returns a double and when you cast to int, you could run into overflow issues

Comment: Yes, reading the relevant documentation is something that should have been done before the question was even posted at all.

Comment: "...when you cast to int, you could run into overflow issues"  There should be no cast, but rather a conversion, i.e. Convert.ToInt32, if an `int` is required.

Comment: I was referring to the code block in the question where the dif_minutes is int rather than double.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `TotalMinutes` property:

```
dt1.Subtract(dt2).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: Just note that the `TotalMinutes` property is type `double` rather than `int`.  `Minutes` is the whole minutes left after the whole days and hours have been taken off while `TotalMinutes` is the entire time period as minutes.